# what does -753 mean in terms of timezone in `pd.Timestamp`

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

```
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
t1 = pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 6, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=tz))
t1
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('2019-02-06 17:00:00-0753', tz='America/Los_Angeles')
```

Why -0753?

**Update**: 
After some research, this way seems to work:
I could be not doing it the right way, see below

```
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
t1 = datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 6, 17, 0, 0)
t1 = tz.localize(t1)
t1 = pd.Timestamp(t1)
t1
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('2019-02-06 17:00:00-0800', tz='America/Los_Angeles')
```

What kind of object should `tzinfo` be when passed to `datetime.datetime` then?

Comment: `-0753` is timezone offset. But for Los Angeles it should be `-0700`, so .. I have no idea why such as number provided :D

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I feel it's likely related to day saving time issue, but don't know how it's dealt with.

Comment: Are you using pytz for switch between timezones?

Comment: Now, I want to understand how dst is dealt with when e.g. converting UTC time to America/Los_Angeles

Comment: Daylight saving does not make sense. With dst it should be -0800 and not 0753

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why, but this weird timezone offset comes from pytz. See code below:

```
>>>print(datetime(2019, 5, 10, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')))
2019-05-10 00:00:00-07:53

>>>print(pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles').localize(datetime(2019, 5, 10)))
2019-05-10 00:00:00-07:00
```

So, if you're trying to create datetime and provide `tzinfo`, it will create this offset.

**Upd.**

I've checked pytz [docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) and found next:

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.
>
> ...
>
> It is safe for timezones without daylight saving transitions though, such as UTC.

Okay, they tell it, but don't point to the reason. Let's try to find it. In pytz sources I've found version of [IANA database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) they use:

```
OLSON_VERSION = '2019a'
```

After downloading and unpacking this database in file "northamerica" I've found next:

```
# Zone  NAME        GMTOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone America/Los_Angeles -7:52:58 - LMT 1883 Nov 18 12:07:02
            -8:00   US  P%sT    1946
            -8:00   CA  P%sT    1967
            -8:00   US  P%sT
```

`-7:52:58` is pretty close to `-07:53` we've got.

**Conclusion:** Somewehere in pytz there's database which contains all known timezone offsets. When we pass tzinfo into constructor of datetime it get first known timezone and use it when localize method, which call [replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) and pass tzinfo, somehow get correct timezone offset.

To check it I've found in same file another timezone:

```
# Zone  NAME        GMTOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone America/Toronto    -5:17:32 -  LMT 1895
            -5:00   Canada  E%sT    1919
            -5:00   Toronto E%sT    1942 Feb  9  2:00s
            -5:00   Canada  E%sT    1946
            -5:00   Toronto E%sT    1974
            -5:00   Canada  E%sT
```

And then I've launched next code:

```
>>>print(datetime(2019, 5, 10, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Toronto')))
2019-05-10 00:00:00-05:18
```

As you see, result is same. It used `-5:17:32`, which is first offset from the list.